# AWS S3 routing rules for appending .html or index.html

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, routes

I have a Jekyll generated static HTML page that I use as my homepage. Currently I am trying to migrate it from traditional hosting service on AWS S3. So far I managed to publish all of my files on bucket and enable website hosting, but when it comes to browsing, page is broken.

Basically `subpages/` is not rewritten into `subpages/index.html` and `subpages/entry1` is not rewritten into `subpages/entry1.html`.

Earlier I used `.htaccess` config like this one:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*subpages/[^.]+)/?$ $1.html
RewriteRule ^(.*subpages2/[^.]+)/?$ $1.html
```

to rewrite it as intended.

How could such behavior be recreated with S3 routing rules? [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html) presents rather limited set of config options in this regard and does not give examples how such scenario could be achieved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon S3 does not have extensive re-writing capabilities.

You can specify a default document to read when a directory reference is specified. For example, you can specify that the default document is `index.html`. That way, if `/` is requested, then it will serve up /index.html. But this is a per-bucket setting, so you cannot have different rules for different folders.

You could modify your Jekyll configuration to generate `subpages/entry1/index.html` from `subpages/entry1.html`. This way, your URLs will continue to work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to fix the reference to have subpages/entry1.html at the first place. Than you do not need a rewrite.

Comment: Personally, I find this solution inferior as it force me to change all default settings and breaks existing URLs. But if it cannot be done other way...

Comment: Inferior to what exactly? S3 doesn't support adding .html extensions to arbitrary paths, so you simply can't use those URLs with S3. If you think that makes S3 inferior to your previous hosting solution, then by all means continue using your previous hosting solution.

Comment: Inferior in terms of serving bookmark friendly URLs compared to Apache, `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9000` or `jekyll serve`. I expected paid service to be configurable to suit my project, not the other way round.